# Laravel how to use code inside collective dropdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective, laravel-form

I have an array and i use foreach, below is code

```
@foreach($param2 as $par)
{{$par->account}}
@endforeach
```

now i want to use the $par->account in drop down

i am using below code

```
    {!! Form::select('[
'option' => $par->account
], null, ['placeholder' => '<select>','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

there are 3 items in array, but it shows only single item.

Answer (score 1):

Generate array and send it from controller :

Controller :

```
foreach($param2 as $par) {
    $accounts[] = $par->account;
}
```

In view :

```
{!! Form::select('name', $accounts, null, ['placeholder' => '<select>','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```